Bishop Gaussian Basis
In Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Christopher Bishop he says in Section 3.3.2 titled Predictive distribution

If we used localised basis functions such as Gaussians, then in regions away
from the basis function centres, the contribution from the second term in the predictive variance (3.59) will go to zero, leaving only the noise contribution $\beta^{−1}$ . Thus,
the model becomes very conﬁdent in its predictions when extrapolating outside the
region occupied by the basis functions, which is generally an undesirable behaviour.

But just before this paragraph it says

Note that the predictive uncertainty depends on $x$ and is smallest in the
neighbourhood of the data points. Also note that the level of uncertainty decreases
as more data points are observed.

In the figure it seems that the variance is high when away from data points.

Both things are true: 1) Within the area where we have Gaussian basis functions defined, variance is smaller near the data than away from it 2) Outside of the area where we have Gaussian basis functions, the variance will be small (because of our modeling assumptions which imply that the function is zero/constant there). If we had extended the x-axes on Figure 3.8 without adding any more data or basis functions, we would see the variances collapse again on the far left/right sides.

Oh, ok so between the 3rd and 4th data point in bottom left graph the distance is not "big enough" for the model to be too confident? Thanks

For phenomenon (2), it's not about the distance between data points; rather, it's about the distance between a prediction location and the basis function centers.

Oh, ok thanks, that makes sense.
